# Comparing real numbers in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I need something like Double.compare in Java. Is there a way to accomplish it? Thanks.

Comment: This should be pretty easy to write as a utility function using the comparison operators on your Number objects.  I don't know of a built-in library function to mimic Java's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function compareNumber( a:Number, b:Number ):int
{
    if ( a < b )
        return -1;
    else if ( a > b )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```